# `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

After having difficulty but succeeding in installing mysql2 v 0.4.2 using

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.2' -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

I am now stuck with the following error when running `bundle exec rails s`

```
`require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
    from /Users/jmayer/workspace/sekai-property/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/jmayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.5
```

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

I have tried every thing I have found on stack overflow regarding the error but with no luck.

I'm simply trying to start a development server, create a database, etc.

Comment: I have same problem with `Rails 5.2.2` - `ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin18]` and `mysql2 (0.5.2)`
`bundle exec rails s` does not work (and I have executed `bundle` with following in my `gemfile` `gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'`

Answer (score 0):

> Since you are using `bundle exec` it is only taking in account gems
>   present in Gemfile, so you need to put it there.

Include

```
gem mysql2
```

in your Gemfile (which is present on root directory of your project)

then run

```
bundle install
```

Then you can run

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately there are many details I did not list. mysql2 is in the gemfile. I have run ```bundle install``` after running ```gem install...```. Additionally I have run ```rails s``` without ```bundle exec```